# please help me. I have probability generating function as follows, how can get the mixture distribution of $X$ from it?

Tags: probability, derivatives, random-variables, generating-functions, density-function

$$
G_x (s)=\frac{s \cdot (1-q(1-α+α \cdot s))}{(1-q \cdot s)(1-α+α \cdot s)} 
$$

Or, in another way, how can I say that a random variable follows a certain distribution with a certain probability and follows another distribution with a complementary probability?

I really couldn't find what was needed and I am very grateful for the help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmj31.jpg)

Comment: Is there more information? Are $q$ and $\alpha$ parameters of the distribution of $X$?

Comment: thank u for cooperation ..  
Y has truncated geometric distribution (P=1-q)
f(y)=(1-q) q^(y-1),y=1,2,…
then Pgf is 
G_y (s)=((1-q)s)/((1-qs))
I have model as      Y_t=α*Y_(t-1)+X_t
Where * is called thinging operator and has special properties 
then Pgf is  
G_x (s)=(G_y (s))/(G_y (1-α+α*s) )=(s*(1-q(1-α+α*s)))/((1-q*s)(1-α+α*s))
What the pmf of X
how can I say that a random variable follows a certain distribution with a certain probability + follows another distribution with a complementary probability?

Comment: Is it given that Y is truncated? Because the pgf you provide for Y is the pgf of a regular geometric distribution?

Comment: Furthermore, can you explain more about the thinging operator? In your recursion you use a plus, I do not see the operator appear, do I miss something here?

Comment: Yes Y has zero truncated geometric distribution (shifted geometric (p))
f(y)=(1-q) q^(y-1),y=1,2,…
then Pgf is 
G_y (s)=((1-q)s)/((1-qs))
I have model as      Y_t=α o Y_(t-1)+X_t
Where   o   is called thinging operator and has special properties 
then Pgf is  
G_x (s)=(G_y (s))/(G_y (1-α+α s) )=(s(1-q(1-α+α s)))/((1-q s)(1-α+α s))
From G_x (s)  What the pmf of X ?
how can I say that a random variable follows a certain distribution with a certain probability + follows another distribution with a complementary probability?